# NSURLConnection object cannot be release？

Tags: objective-c

simple code is here.

```
.h
@interface testXML : UIViewController {
    NSURLConnection *connect;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connect;   

.m
@synthesize connect;
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
    self.connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When the viewDidLoad was called, I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should use NSURLConnection(assuming you have the desired link in string)
You can release the connection after initiating it. If you want to use it multiple times, make connection and iVar and call the below methods.

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]  initWithURL:[NSURL URLwithString:string]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request  delegate:self]                    
   [request release];
   [connection release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But the problem is when I need to release the object and point it to a new object. It will be down.

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error { connection  = nil; }
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
connection = nil; }